# Spacy NLP - Chunking with Regular Expressions

Tags: python, nlp, part-of-speech, spacy

Spacy includes the `noun_chunks` functionality to retrieve set of Noun -Phrases. 
The function `english_noun_chunks` (attached below) uses `word.pos == NOUN`

```
def english_noun_chunks(doc):
    labels = ['nsubj', 'dobj', 'nsubjpass', 'pcomp', 'pobj',
              'attr', 'root']
    np_deps = [doc.vocab.strings[label] for label in labels]
    conj = doc.vocab.strings['conj']
    np_label = doc.vocab.strings['NP']
    for i in range(len(doc)):
        word = doc[i]
        if word.pos == NOUN and word.dep in np_deps:
            yield word.left_edge.i, word.i+1, np_label
        elif word.pos == NOUN and word.dep == conj:
            head = word.head
            while head.dep == conj and head.head.i < head.i:
                head = head.head
            # If the head is an NP, and we're coordinated to it, we're an NP
            if head.dep in np_deps:
                yield word.left_edge.i, word.i+1, np_label
```

I would like to get chunks from a sentence that maintain some regular expression. For example, I phrase of zero or more adjectives followed by one or more nouns.

```
{(<JJ>)*(<NN | NNS | NNP>)+}
```

Is it possible w/o overriding the `english_noun_chunks` function?

Answer (score 4):

You could rewrite this function without losing any performance, since it's implemented in pure python, but why not just filter those chunks after you get them?

```
import re
import spacy

def filtered_chunks(doc, pattern):
  for chunk in doc.noun_chunks:
    signature = ''.join(['<%s>' % w.tag_ for w in chunk])
    if pattern.match(signature) is not None:
      yield chunk

nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = nlp(u'Great work!')
pattern = re.compile(r'(<JJ>)*(<NN>|<NNS>|<NNP>)+')

print(list(filtered_chunks(doc, pattern)))
```

Comment: what about the fact that this function is translated to C by Cython?

Comment: You are right, that file has `.pyx` extension and you will loose some performance if you rewrite it. But do you need to rewrite it or you could simply filter end results?